# Copying chart from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a chart into Word. I looked up a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871774/copy-and-paste-an-excel-chart-with-a-vba-macro-in-word) that says to do something like this:

```
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = True

Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    .ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
End With
With Selection
    .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdInLine, _
    Placement:=wdInLine
End With
wordApp.Documents.Close
wordApp.Application.Quit
```

I tried to change the `With selection` section to just `wordApp.Documents.Selection.Pastespecial` which causes some weird things to happen and ends up somehow pasting a screen shot of the first sheet in the workbook, and crashing Excel. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in this part of your code:

```
With Selection
    .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdInLine, _
    Placement:=wdInLine
End With
```

you can solve your problem changing it with this:

```
With wordDoc.Application.Selection
    .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdInLine, _
    Placement:=wdInLine
End With
```

**Explanation:** Running your code from an excel macro, the Selection object will resolve to the current selection in your excel sheet, you need to specify the scope of the selection to apply your command on your word document instead of your current Excel workbook.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. This now gives me an error: "Word has encountered a problem"